# Dynamic dashboards in Google Sheet with individual filters per user

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

​Hi

when switching from Excel to Google Sheets one big disadvantage is that due to the real time collaboration it is not possible to have interactive management dashboards anymore where every user can individually filter aggregated data or graphs (e. g. with a data slicer). When more than one person is accessing the dashboard everybody sees the individual chosen validation filters of the last person that changed them.

One solution that has been suggested a lot is to create one spreadsheet with the data and a second spreadsheet with the dashboard in which the data is imported with IMPORTRANGE. Every manager will get a personal copy of the dashboard file.
This solution is not applicable when you have a lot of managers (>50) or when you want to change the dashboard frequently.

So I was thinking of different solutions and came up with these 3:

---

**1. Build the dashboard as WebApp**

Data will be stored in Sheets and the WebApp will display the aggregated data or a specific dataset

Pros:

- Can use all advantages of HTML and Javascript

Cons:

- Need to have additional skills in HTML, Javascript and CSS
- Not so flexible as Sheets e. g. with Graphs, Data slicers etc.
- Depending on how much data you have the process for searching specific data and visualising it in the WebApp is slow

---

**2. Build the dashboard in Google Data Studio / Looker Studio**

Data will be stored in Sheets and Data Studio / Looker Studio will display the aggregated data or a specific dataset

Pros:

- Good for visualization of all the data

Cons:

- Not good for visualization of a single data set
- Very limited in how to present the data

---

**3. Build the dashboard in the same spreadsheet as the data and make a personal copy of the dashboard-sheet inside the spreadsheet with AppsScript for every user opening the file**

In a spreadsheet the data will be stored in one sheet and a master dashboard will be designed in a second sheet (hidden). Everytime a user opens the spreadsheet a personal copy of the master dashboard-sheet will be created for the specific user and will be deleted when the user exits the spreadsheet.

Pros:

- Can use all the possibilities for visualisation in Sheets (pivot tables, data slicers, graphs, formulas, etc.)

Cons:

- When several users access the spreadsheet at the same time a lot of personal copies of the dashboard are visible
- User has to grant permissions for the AppsScript

---

All of these three solutions are not really good. Do you have any other suggestions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use [filter views](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3540681). Filter views are different from regular filters. This feature lets multiple simultaneous users sort, filter and edit the sheet without disturbing each other.

For additional ease of use, you can insert links in the frozen section of the sheet to easily switch between filter views, instead of having to go to **Data > Filter views** to switch. See the [Filter views example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ME5b4J6fQa8RRainxGtQkwTKFCg96N8_k6kCe8ABNyk/edit#gid=2048818001&fvid=336145647) spreadsheet for an illustration.

From the [documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9245556?hl=en#zippy=%2Cfilters-filter-views-slicers):

> When you apply a filter on a slicer, changes are only visible to you, unless you set them as default.

Comment: Thank your for this idea.
You are right with "multiple simultaneous users (can) sort, filter" the sheet, but from what I know not with "edit".
For example: In the dashboard you have an input field for product id. When you are entering a id some information about sales, pictures etc. are displayed. Even when you are entering a value with activated filter view all the other users see your input.

Comment: And an other problem is that every user has to create this filter view by himself / herself. The example from you is good for a small amount of different filter views but not for >50 filter views for all the managers.

Comment: To avoid saving that many filter views, make the dashboard sheet view-only and tell users to use temporary filter views. It's a thing. Slicers create temporary filter views automatically.